# Debug tips for intermittent slow responses from Confluence

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, debugging, confluence

I've started seeing a situation on our internal Atlassian Confluence instance where we get snappy performance most of the time, but a couple of times an hour requests (both read and write operations) just hang for up to a few minutes (longest I've seen is 5 minutes).

I could plough through http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONF34/Performance+Tuning but just wanted to check if anyone could point me to anything obvious.

Our setup uses Confluence standalone fronted by an Apache 2.2 instance on the same host, which uses mod_proxy to forward requests to Confluence.  Apache is set up to use HTTPS for all requests.   We have a MySQL DB on a separate server.

There's no obvious spikes in CPU or memory usage on the Confluence or DB servers, so I don't think garbage collection is the problem, and I've tried increasing the MaxThreads in Apache to no avail.

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Confluence runs under tomcat, not apache, so it's doubtful that modifying things in Apache will help much.

Comment: Sure, I was just looking for low hanging fruit with Apache - any tips for debugging whether Tomcat is running out of resources ?

Comment: That doc you linked to has some recommendations about mitigating performance issues due to periodic JVM garbage collection. I'd start by reading that section.

Comment: Edited the question to make it a bit clearer, but I don't suspect GC is the problem because I'm not seeing any spikes in CPU.

Comment: Have you contacted Atlassian support? They're very good in my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by a badly behaving Active Directory server; we have Confluence hooked up to AD via Crowd using a virtual IP address that points to multiple physical AD servers, and one of the servers was responding very slowly.  I switched to a different VIP using only local servers, and everything looks good.

@ErikA, I've had very good experiences with Atlassian support in the past, but in this case they were no help at all :-(